# uploaded file duplication in host and container by laravel file storage

Tags: laravel, docker, file-upload, file-storage

I configured the laravel application in the docker container on the Ubuntu server. Files uploaded with [laravel file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem) and linked `php artisan storage:link`. Files uploaded to laravel storage are available in both container and host.

> Doesn't that mean duplication of the uploaded files, for example it
> exists in docker container also in project source code in ubuntu
> server?

I know that best way of storing uploaded files is some external space like aws s3, digitalocean spaces...

Comment: How are you actually configuring the container?  If you have a bind mount, there is only one copy of the data but it's visible in both filesystems.  If the data is built into the image, all containers based on the image will share a single copy of it (unless they write an individual file, in which case that file is transparently duplicated for that container).

Comment: @DavidMaze yes I have bind mount. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is no duplication.  The files only exist once on the host machine and are mounted in the container as views (read/write)